# Сколько workers у gunicorn можно запустить на сервере?

Tags: python, linux, django, gunicorn

Есть ubuntu сервер, на котором крутится чат бот на django и меня интересует вопрос: сколько процессов (workers) я могу запустить на этом сервере. По формуле из документации (кол-во_ядер * 2 + 1) получается 3, но мой процессор загружен на 5 процентов при интенсивной работе, при 3 процессах. Могу ли я запустить допустим 12? Если нет, то почему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> сколько процессов (workers) я могу запустить на этом сервере.

Попробуйте ввести команду ps, которая распечатывает список уже работающих процессов - их гораздо больше!

На самом деле, макс. количество процессов определяется параметрами конфигурации ядра:

> Версия 2.6-от 17 декабря 2003:
>    - увеличено максимальное количество процессов с 32 000 до 1 млрд;

Хватит Вам столько ? :-)

Comment: С удовольствием бы запустил 1 млрд, но суть не в максимально возможном кол-во процессов в ОС, а какое максимальное количество "обработчиков" gunicorn я могу запустить. Скорее всего я неправильно выразился, использовав понятие "процесс"

Comment: Ну да, я действительно не понял Вашего вопроса. Почитал маленько про этот gunicorn. Нашёл даже приведённую вами формулу. Она кажется мне очень(!) странной. Эта формула полностью совпадает с формулой, задающей  число нитей GCC при компиляции большой программы. Но ведь это подразумевает исключительно работу на процессоре, без всяких ожиданий. А Ваш чат-бот будет 99.999999% времени ждать прихода сообщения, на которое нужно будет отвечать. С моей точки зрения, эта формула абсолютно неприменима в такой ситуации.

Comment: То есть ставлю столько, сколько душе угодно?

Comment: Просто надо помнить, что каждый запущенный процесс, даже в состоянии ожидания, потребляет ресурсы. Так что, главное, не переборщить. Лично я, на вашем месте, попробовал бы значения (последовательно) 10, 100, 1000... и смотрел-бы, что показывает *top*, Как увидите, что загрузка ЦП возросла до 25% - ну и хватит!

Comment: Понял, спасибо)